# DataGridView doesn't update when assigning datasource of second datagrid

Tags: c#, datagridview, refresh

I have two dataGridViews but only one displayed.
They both have exactly the same columns but different values.
The problem is that only one is displayed and when I select the first or second dataGridView, my dataGridView that was showing someting, stops and doesn't work at all anymore.

I tried this

```
dataGridView1 = DataGridView2;
```

Like this

```
BindingSource b = new BindingSource();                
b.DataSource = dataGridView2.DataSource;
dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
dataGridView1.DataSource = b;
dataGridView1.Visible = true;
dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
```

But nothing is working... And yes, I tried `Update()` and `Refresh()`

Comment: What do you mean by "they have different values"?

Comment: @madan Error 1 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' does not contain a definition for 'Bind' and no extension method 'Bind' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @IvanStoev  I have the same name of the column header. I want to show the first or the second dataGridview  when I want. But when I try to do that, it brakes...

Comment: I get confused. Ok, they have one and the same columns - I got that from the question. But doesn't "different values" mean they are bound to a different data sources?

Comment: @IvanStoev not necessarily? My data  is partly introduced by the user and  the other is generated by my algorithm.  And I don't store it on a online data base, everything is local and after all the cells are filled it exports the data in a specific format.

Comment: **Data Source** is not the same as database. It basically is some sort of a memory list where the data that the grid displays resides. I'm suspecting you work directly with the grids, in which case you don't have a data source at all. DataSource is something you need to set and to contain your data. If you think that the first grid will provide it magically for you, you are on the wrong track.

Comment: is it possible to share the whole program

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can verify your application with help of following simple Example

```
namespace GridView
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataSet ds= new DataSet();
            ds.ReadXml(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\students.xml");
            dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
            dataGridView1.DataMember = "student";
            Application.DoEvents();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BindingSource b = new BindingSource();
            dataGridView2.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
            b.DataSource = dataGridView1.DataSource;
            dataGridView2.DataMember = "student";
            dataGridView2.DataSource = b;
        }
    }
}
```

I think you miss the **DataMember** attribute I assign the datasource of grid 1 to grid 2 and this works for me also.